# Clean-up duplications etc. in virtual memory(RAM)

Tags: memory

My laptops virtual memory(RAM) is very low. I run Ubuntu 10.4. I uninstalled many software programs but still it does not seem to help. I have not installed the regular updates in a couple of months now because of low space. Is there a way of doing a clean-up on file duplications, unnecessary temp files, and unused files that will ease up some space. I never experienced low memory issues when I was running Windows and the painful Vista. I can't see that it should be a problem now.

Answer (score 2):

RAM is not virtual. How many RAM do you have?

```
free
```

Updates don't occupy RAM, they occupy disk space. How big are your partitions?

```
df -h
```

/tmp-Files are cleaned on every reboot. Firefox (do you use it? If you are low on RAM, try opera) can produce big caches. You may reduce the size from the settings dialog therein.

You may have some cache from installs/updates.

```
sudo apt-cache clean
```

should erase it.

Of course, 2 or 3 videos may occupy more space than the whole rest of your OS.

Unused files is somehow hard to decide. You may look in the menu for applications which you don't need, and remove them with syanptics.

Where do you think duplicate files come from?

You don't talk about swap-space, when talking about Virtual RAM?

```
swapon -s
```

Swap is exclusively used for swapping. You can gain some diskspace by repartitioning, if you made it much too big. 2x your real memory is a reasonable size. You never do manipulate its content by hand.